# How can I allow sha1WithRSAEncryption during nginx ssl_client_verify?

Tags: nginx, nginx-ingress

My nginx server is successfully verifying most (expected) client certificates, but some older client certificates are getting "400 Bad Request The SSL certificate error" and producing this log entry -- "client SSL certificate verify error: (68:CA signature digest algorithm too weak)"

Is there a way to allow older signature digest algorithms?

Running `openssl list -digest-algorithms` shows sha1RSA, but it isn't included in the TLSv1.2 -  Handshake Protocol - Certificate Request Message.

Versions: 
 - helm chart nginx-ingress v1.1.3
 - nginx-ingress-controller v0.21.0
 - nginx v1.15.6
 - openssl 1.1.1

-- **Update** --

To verify client certificates that are signed with weak digest algorithms, append `@SECLEVEL=0` to your ssl_ciphers list, i.e. `ssl_ciphers 'HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5@SECLEVEL=0';`

[discussion](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/3869) and [openssl reference](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/man1/ciphers.html).

I don't understand the full implications of `@SECLEVEL`, so best solution is to push for updated client certificates!

Comment: Did you find a solution?