# how to tell nginx to ignore some certificate errors?

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, openssl, nginx-ingress

I am using nginx ingress in k8s and have enabled client certificate authentication.

However, some of my clients are using very old certificates, thus I see openssl errors like
error:66(certificate key too weak)

error:26(unsupported certificate purpose)

**How to tell nginx to skip such checking so that my clients can connect ?**

I tried to add snippet to set @SECLEVEL=0 following these https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/virtualserver-and-virtualserverroute-resources/#using-snippets and [How can I allow sha1WithRSAEncryption during nginx ssl_client_verify?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54797480/how-can-i-allow-sha1withrsaencryption-during-nginx-ssl-client-verify)

And then try to grep the added config in the generated conf files in **/etc/nginx/conf.d** in nginx-ingress pods, but I  can't find the snippets are added.

I've enabled snippets by adding the command line argument per https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/global-configuration/command-line-arguments#-enable-snippets

**What is missing here ?**

I am using nginx-ingress version 3.1.0